# Central Event Dispatcher with Templated Event types in C++

Tags: c++, events

I've been learning C++ and trying to implement various idioms from other languages I'm familiar with.

Recently I've tried to implement a central EventDispatcher which multiple objects can register events that can take N number of arguments, and a single call to EventDispatcher::dispatch(event_name) would call all registered event callbacks.

First I created a template class for Event;

```
template <typename ..._args>
class Event
{
public:
    //Alias for template callback
    using _callback = std::function<void(_args...)>;

    //Ctor & Dtor
    explicit Event(std::string const& name, _callback const& cb) : _name(name), _cbFunc(cb) {}
    ~Event() {}

    //Accessors
    std::string const& getName() const { return this->_name; }

    //Methods
    void trigger(_args... a) { this->_cbFunc(a...); }
private:
    //Event identifier
    std::string _name;
    //Event callback - can't be changed inside event.
    _callback const _cbFunc;
};
```

With this structure I can define events like in the following example:

```
void testCallback(int a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

Event<int> _event("TestEvent", std::bind(&testCallback, _1));
_event.trigger(20); //This will actually output 20 to the console.
```

What I want to do next is, have an EventDispatcher class which should be defined like:

```
class EventDispatcher
{
public:
    EventDispatcher();
    ~EventDispatcher();

    void registerEvent(**Event of any type**);
    void dispatchEvent(std::string const& eventName, ....args);
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<**Event of any type**>> _eventList;
};
```

so that I can make calls like this;

```
EventDispatcher _dispatcher;
_dispatcher.registerEvent(_event); //event defined in the previous example.

_dispatcher.dispatchEvent("TestEvent", 20); //this should call event's trigger() method with arguments passed to it actually.
```

However I couldn't figure out how to implement a central dispatcher and have it be able to register templatized event instances, and then pass variable number of arguments to dispatchEvent(...) and make it trigger all events in a vector of templatized events.

How can I achieve such functionality? Is my thought proccess correct or far from c++ way of implementing such a system? Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: What exactly should happen if you attempt to dispatch to an event with the wrong type of arguments?  What if you register an event that takes an rvalue to a type from A.DLL, then call it with an instance of a type from B.DLL?  What if in one of the two scopes there is a conversion operator from the B.DLL type to the A.DLL type?  These are 3 different questions.  There are *many* ways to do something that sortof works, but why do you want a central dispatcher that handles different signatures when any type mismatch is a type error that could be caught at compile time?

Comment: Great questions, like I said I'm beginner in c++ and want to learn. The reason I want a central event dispatcher is to be able to use it with different classes can register to a "dispatcher" in, say, my main application module. What other options would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a solution with an abstract base class (`IEvent`) for the event class (`Event`)
and a template dispatcher method with variadic arguments and a `dynamic_cast`.

Apstrac base class with the abstract method `getName`:

```
class IEvent
{
public:
    virtual const std::string & getName() const = 0;
};
```

Your event class derived from `IEvent`:

```
template <typename ..._args>
class Event : public IEvent
{
public:
    //Alias for template callback
    using _callback = std::function<void(_args...)>;

    //Ctor & Dtor
    //template< typename T_CB >
    explicit Event( const std::string & name, const _callback & cb ) : _name(name), _cbFunc(cb) {}
    ~Event() {}

    //Accessors
    virtual const std::string & getName() const override { return this->_name; }

    //Methods
    void trigger(_args... a) { this->_cbFunc(a...); }
private:
    //Event identifier
    std::string _name;
    //Event callback - can't be changed inside event.
    _callback const _cbFunc;
};
```

The dispatcher with the template method:

```
class EventDispatcher
{
public:
    EventDispatcher() {}
    ~EventDispatcher()
    {
      for ( auto el : _eventList )
      {
        for ( auto e : el.second )
          delete e;
      }
    }

    void registerEvent( IEvent *event )
    {
      if ( event )
          _eventList[event->getName()].push_back( event );
    }

    template <typename ..._args>
    void dispatchEvent( const std::string & eventName, _args...a )
    {
      auto it_eventList = _eventList.find( eventName );
      if ( it_eventList == _eventList.end() )
        return;
      for ( auto ie : it_eventList->second )
      {
        if ( Event<_args...> * event = dynamic_cast<Event<_args...>*>( ie ) )
          event->trigger( a... );
      }
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<IEvent*>> _eventList;
};
```

And finally the application:

```
void testCallback(int a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  EventDispatcher eventDisp;
  eventDisp.registerEvent( new Event<int>( "TestEvent", &testCallback ) );

  eventDisp.dispatchEvent( "TestEvent", 20 );

  return 0;
}
```